# Is a correct heading-level outline even possible on site with global navigation, sidebar, footers etc…?

Tags: html, sections, html-heading

**Since the HTML5 document outline isn't implemented by any user-agent** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines), we're left with the good old heading-level outline.
I'm all for respect of standards, so I'm trying to find a good heading-level outline to reuse and adapt.

Using the **W3C validator tool** with the « show outline » option, I've checked a dozen of websites, some of them being created by accessibility evangelists : **Mozilla**, **Accessiweb**, **Access42**, **WCAG**, **W3C**…. 
But I haven't found any website where every prerequisite is met :

- The **Mozilla blog** (https://blog.mozilla.org/) outline is plain wrong : they used h2 for the headings of every article, but they used h3 for others sections in the page, so it looks like every global content (« More Mozilla Blogs », « More articles »…) is linked to the last article.

[The Mozilla Blog homepage heading-level outline on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVq42.png)

- Several sites skips one or more levels in their headings hierarchy

[A W3C post heading-level outline on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqFox.png)

- This **WebAIM** article (https://webaim.org/techniques/screenreader/) has a coherent outline, but the first heading on the webpage is an h2

[A WebAIM post heading-level outline on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JazT.png)

- This **Accessiweb** page (http://www.accessiweb.org/index.php/expert-accessiweb-en-evaluation.html) has a coherent outline.
  It isn't HTML5 though, so the developer didn't have to deal with warnings like « nav element with no heading », and most of all, every h1 of every page of this site is the title of the website (« Accessiweb »), the page title is an h2… Looks like a bad idea for accessibility and SEO.

[Heading-level outline from accessiweb.org on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r8Cf.png)

If h1 is the title of the post, **what heading should be used for global sections** (like navigation or footer) ?

- if one use h1, it breaks the rule of « only one H1 per page »
- if one use h2, the hierarchy is wrong (cf. the Mozilla blog example)
- if one doesn't use any heading there is a warning from the W3C validator (« nav element with no heading »)

I don't even know if it is a good thing for screenreaders users to constantly have the global sections in their heading list, they probably would find it annoying to hear « *h1 Global navigation - h1 My post title - h1 Subscribe to our newsletter - h1 Other content (Footer)* » when they use the heading navigation on every page.
Or, maybe on the contrary they need it on every page and it would be annoying for them to not have access to every content on every page? What an headhache!

So : **is a correct and coherent heading-level outline even possible on site with global sections *outside of the HTML Document Outline*** ?

I understand there is no « One size fits all » HTML structure, but most sites have a header, a global navigation, a main zone and a footer so I guess we can at least have a boilerplate with these items.

Answer (score 0):

For Good HTML Coding, H1 is one per page. for all there title you can use h2 code. then after h3, h4, ....

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.
1. I've read in several places that there must be only one h1 heading, but it is a myth or an official recommandation. Can you provide a source ?
2. What do you mean exactly by « for all there title you can use h2 code » ? Do you suggest something like this:

+ h2 Global navigation (nav)
h1 Title of my post (main)
+ h2 Related posts (sidebar)
+ h2 Subscribe to our newsletter (footer)
+ h2 Contact (footer)

Because that wouldn't be a coherent level-heading outline…

Comment: @noelno - Only one h1 heading per page is a myth. No HTML spec has ever required that. The requirement is that *top level* headings on a page must be h1 and subordinate headings are h2, h3 etc. The normal practice is for each page to have only one top level heading, but there's no requirement that that be the case.

Comment: Thank for your input @Alohci.

Comment: try to use one time H1, and you can use all other header tag more than one time. its good for your website onpage seo